# How to know programmatically if a view or a layout file exists in grails

Tags: grails, view, layout

I want to know programmatically if a view or a layout exists in grails.

I am thinking in obtain the absolutepath and ask for File.exists but I don't know how to obtain this path for every enviroment.

I had tried `groovyPagesTemplateEngine.getUriWithinGrailsViews('a-view.gsp')` without success.

Can you give me any pointer?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see 2 possibilities

#### Search for view file

If you build a war file you will see that *views* are stored in *WEB-INF/grails-app/views*. You can search for that resource.

```
def uri = this.getClass().getResource("/grails-app/views/...").toURI()
if(new File(uri).exists()){...}
```

#### Use PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver

Find a inspiration in [assertView](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#xOoVUSR8ZWM/grails/src/groovy/grails/test/GrailsUrlMappingsTestCase.groovy&q=GrailsUrlMappingsTestCase&d=5) method of GrailsUrlMappingsTestCase.

```
def patternResolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver()
def pathPattern = "grails-app/views/" + ((controller) ? "$controller/" : "") + "${view}.*"
if (!patternResolver.getResources(pathPattern)) {...}
```

Answer (score 18):

Since Grails 2.0, you can inject a [GrailsConventionGroovyPageLocator](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/pages/discovery/GrailsConventionGroovyPageLocator.html):

```
GrailsConventionGroovyPageLocator groovyPageLocator
```

and call

```
groovyPageLocator.findViewByPath(...)
groovyPageLocator.findTemplateByPath(...)
```

to check if views or templates exist.

Comment: This also works quite nicely... `groovyPageLocator.findTemplate("/same/as/render/template")`  (If you have a template file        at `/grails-app/views/same/as/render/_template.gsp`)

Comment: I know this was ages ago, but I get nothing from this. It returns null every time, event when I manually setGrailsApplication()

Comment: In recent Grails versions (perhaps since GSP became a plugin) the exact type of the page locator has changed. Cheat by omitting the class when injecting it, like `def groovyPageLocator`

Comment: It works in Grails 3 declaring like this: `def groovyPageLocator`

Answer (score 4):

Additionally to what amra said, you can also use [`grailsAttributes`](http://www.grails.org/Controller+Dynamic+Methods)*(see docs for [GrailsApplicationAttributes](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/servlet/GrailsApplicationAttributes.html))*. Quick example:

```
private templateExists(String name) {
    def template = grailsAttributes.getTemplateUri(name, request)
    def resource = grailsAttributes.pagesTemplateEngine
                                   .getResourceForUri(template)
    return resource && resource.file && resource.exists()
}
```

This example is of course for templates but as you can see from the docs, similar method exists for views too.