# Grails 2.4.5 and the 404 becoming 500

Tags: grails, nullpointerexception

I have this app that needs to run with gsp reloading active (don't judge me, I already do it daily myself). The app has recently being ported from 2.2.3 to 2.4.5 and it almost went flawlessly.

Now in the action of a controller, I write:

```
render(view:red,model:pMap());
```

Where 'red' is the path of the view and pMap generates the scope.

It all works well except for one thing. When the 'red' path is referencing a missing resource, I would expect it to go 404 as it used to do in the previous version.

What I get instead is a terrifying:

```
NullPointerException occurred when processing request: [GET] /app/ass
Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Needless to say the action that handles the error detects a 500 instead of a 404.

Any idea of why this could happen? Anything I could to fix this mess?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can check before the render call, if the view file exists, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391949/how-to-know-programmatically-if-a-view-or-a-layout-file-exists-in-grails). When it doesn't exist you can change the status code to 404, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429388/how-can-i-return-a-404-50x-status-code-from-a-grails-controller).

As far as I know it throws an NPE, because a toString() is called in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.metaclass.RenderDynamicMethod#renderView on a null map value, because the view doesn't exist.

Comment: It doesn't look like. Maybe this site helps a little bit http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.x/guide/upgradingFrom22.html